# How to manage ECS docker instance, zéro to N with Amazon MQ queues

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, rabbitmq, amazon-ecs, amazon-mq

in the context of batch and microservices.

I don't want use AWS Lambda with the problem of constructor lock.

However, my team don't want start ECS docker instance if no batch is running. I am looking for any solution, with an instance docker all time running, with Saga orchestrator inside. Saga send message in rabbitMQ. After if one message is waiting inside queue, an instance of consumer is started. After the end of process, if no new message inside queue after one hour the instance is stopped.

Have you solution in AWS context ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you could do [auto-scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-auto-scaling.html) on the ECS service with the MQ [MessageReadyCount](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/security-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch.html) metric as the auto-scaling metric.

Comment: Do you now if it's possible to stop task ECS and not juste ajuste cluster capacity ? With your solution. If I have 10 microservice on cluster, with no batch in process, I want zero task ECS running, if no message in queue

Comment: Yes it's possible. You can have auto-scaling set the desired service count to 0.